# How to get the value of two input fields at same time in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

**Here is the form and I want to get the value of both name and age when the user submits the form.**

```
<form>
    <input type='text' name='name'></input>
    <input type='number' name='age'></input>
   <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of ReactJS? At least the homepage introduction? That talks about getting the value of a single field, and you can then extrapolate to two.

Answer (score -1):

### Controlled components (React way)

You have ro store both values in state.
Then you use them in form's `onSubmit`.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

```js
/* component init */
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    value1: '',
    value2: ''
  }
}
/* handle changes */
onChange1(event) {
  this.setState({ value1: event.target.value });
}

onChange2(event) {
  this.setState({ value2: event.target.value });
}

/* submit method */
  onSubmit(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    const value1 = this.state.value1;
    const value2 = this.state.value2;
    console.log(value1, value2);
  }

/* render */
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}> 
   <input type="text" value={this.state.value1} onChange={this.onChange1} /> 
   <input type="number" value={this.state.value2} onChange={this.onChange2} /> 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

### Uncontrolled components (not React way)

If you want to use uncontrolled components (don't store values yourswlf) you have to use `refs`.

More about refs https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html.

```js
/* component init */
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.input1 = React.createRef(); 
  this.input2 = React.createRef(); 
}

/* submit method */
  handleSubmit(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    const value1 = this.input1.current.value;
    const value2 = this.input2.current.value;
    console.log(value1, value2);
  }

/* render */
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
   <input type="text" ref={this.input1} /> 
   <input type="number" ref={this.input2} /> 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: can I do it without using state

Comment: see uncontrolled components topic :)

Comment: I am getting an error "Cannot read property 'value' of null" on the console log

Comment: Let's try to move both createRef from `componentDidMount` to `constructor`

Comment: You can do it without state, however that is neither necessary nor preferred in React.

Comment: @MaxStarling your answer talks about using state, then you do not use state, you use refs.

Comment: @Victor I answered about state briefly, he asked about case without state and I described it in details

Comment: @Victor now I described both anyway :)

Comment: The html FormData api works as well for leaving the components uncontrolled without refs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData